Kite problem (Thompson, Page 47, Problem 9)
My quandary regards, is this even possible using a right triangle?
The question: A three-mile wind (Assumed 3 mph) blowing on a level (Assumed at a consistent level) is carrying a kite directly away from a child. How high is the kite when it is directly over a point 100 ft away and they are playing out the string at the rate of 88 ft a minute?
Many of the prior problems have used right triangles though this one has a certain level of vagueness and ambiguity.
My conclusions: I had converted the rate of 88 ft per minute to a mile per hour and drew up the relations in the succeeding link. My drafting of the problem
Using the time and distance relations I got, $h=t$ & $x=3t$.
Giving, $y=\sqrt{t^2-3t^2}$, which is impossible without imaginary solutions. Please help, I'm sure this is an uncertainty on my behalf.

You didn't use that $x$ is 100ft away. Use that to calculate $t$ then calculate $h$ based on that $t$.

@CyclotomicField I don’t think that helps with the OP’s problem, since it still gives an imaginary y

@ethanolex The level is not imaginary. It is constant. At the level the kite is flying, there is a constant speed wind blowing it away from the child.

The height of the kite is a constant. The problem is telling you that the kite is moving away from the child at a constant speed of $3$ mph. You correctly computed the speed the string is being let out at $1$ mph.
Using the pythagorean theorem and implicit differentiation we get that $$x^2+y^2=h^2\\2x\frac{dx}{dt}+2y\frac{dy}{dt}=2h\frac{dh}{dt}$$ and , since the height $y$ is constant, we get $$2x\frac{dx}{dt}=2h\frac{dh}{dt}\implies 
 x\frac{dx}{dt}=h\frac{dh}{dt}$$
Since the speed that the kite is moving away from the child is three times as much as how fast the string is being let out (regardless of the units), when the kite is $100$ feet away, we get $$h=300\text{ ft}$$
Finally, the pythagorean theorem gives us the height $y=\sqrt{(300)^2-(100)^2}=200\sqrt{2}$ ft.

Of course, implicit differentiation makes sense. I hesitated to do as such since the author hasn't taught it at such a stage. Thanks.
